# Export file system(/etc/exports) using Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

Anyone guide me to export file system using Ansible after adding entry in /etc/exports file...

Comment: what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

If it's Linux you might want to reuse my Ansible Galaxy role [linux_postinstall](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/linux_postinstall) task [nfsd](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/nfsd.yml).

Create /etc/exports

```
- name: "nfsd: Configure exports"
  template:
    src: "exports.j2"
    dest: "/etc/exports"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0644"
  notify: reload nfsd
```

with template [exports.j2](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/templates/exports.j2)

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}
{% for item in lp_nfsd_exports %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

and reload nfsd with the [handler](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/handlers/main.yml) "reload nfsd"

```
- name: reload nfsd
  systemd: name="{{ lp_nfsd_reload_service }}" state="reloaded"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple command like the following.

But note that its not idempotent(one that can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application). The task is executed each time the playbook runs.

The final task(way below in the following playbook) is what you are look for(exportfs -rav).

```
- hosts: all
  name: Make changes to storage node. 
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Install NFS Server.
    apt:
      name: nfs-kernel-server
      state: present

  - name: Ensure volumes directory exists 
    file:
      path: /export/volumes
      state: directory 
      mode: 0777

  - name: Ensure pod inside volumes directory exists 
    file:
      path: /export/volumes/pod
      state: directory 
      mode: 0777

  - name: Ensure required entries are made to hosts file. # Notes 1232
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/exports
      state: present
      line: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - '/export/volumes  *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure)' 

  - name: Restart nfs-kernel-server.service 
    ansible.builtin.systemd:
      daemon_reload: yes
      state: started
      name: nfs-kernel-server.service

  - name: Re-export the share
    command: exportfs -rav
```